# how to go live with the sample web application for testing deployed on remote server?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have created a sample `web application` and `deployed` it on my `remote server desktop`. I am able to run the sample web application `locally` on that `remote server desktop` by `URL : http://localhost:8080/HelloWeb/`.

Now I would like run that application using `URL like : http://<192.168.0.111>/HelloWeb/` from other `desktops` because it  hosted on server but it showing me `404` error.

Steps what I did-

I have downloaded the `Apache Tomcat` core 64 bit zip from http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi.
Copy that folder "apache-tomcat-6.0.37" to `Z: Drive` and extract the folder.
I already had `Java 1.7` installed on my system in `C: Drive`.
Created System Environment of `JAVA_HOME` and `TOMCAT_HOME`.
Copy my sample web application into `apache-tomcat-6.0.37\webapps\`
You can see the structure in the below image.

[image]

web.xml contains-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.mypackage.hello.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/HelloServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Context.XML contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/HelloWeb"/>
```

You can download the source code from [here](http://s3.amazonaws.com/ACB/HelloWeb.zip?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAINHDRCMKC5GUSNFA&Expires=1389292146&Signature=Z6NR/t31pNtqEWMe0IM5X64aU2k=)
I followed [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIbQ0ONU9uM) link to deployed the web application.

**Please help me to run my application form my remote server using URL like - http://<192.168.0.111>/HelloWeb/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should write port number also in the URL like this

```
http://192.168.0.111:8080/HelloWeb/
```

8080 is the default port number

Answer (score 2):

In the Tomcat server folder there is a file `conf/server.xml`. There you can search for `8080` as a keyword, then modify it to 80 (TCP port).  Then you can visit the app using `http://192.168.0.111/HelloWeb/`